# For every complex number $w \neq 0$ there exists $z$ such that $w = \exp(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$ exp($z$) $\neq$ 0. Use that to prove $\forall w \in \mathbb{C}, w \neq 0$ there exists such $z \in \mathbb{C}$ that $w = exp(z)$.

$$
\exp(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}
$$

I only know that $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$.

I did first part with some kind of contradiction

$$
\exp(z)=0 \\
\frac{1}{\exp(-z)} = 0 \text{  }\big{/} \cdot \exp(-z)\\
1 = 0
$$
How can I prove the second one? I can't use polar form to do so.

Comment: In order to have a meaningful answer you should make precise which definition of the exponential function you rely on.

Comment: @arnett Good point. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$w=e^z\implies \frac{1}{w}=e^{-z}$ as $w\ne 0$
Now, by **little Picard's theorem**, the function $e^{-z}$ being *entire* on complex plane takes all values on $\mathbb C$ with atmost one possible exception (i.e. $0$).

Answer (score 1):

If we write $z=a+bi$, with $a, b\in\Bbb R$ and $i^2=-1$, then
$$e^z=e^{a+bi}=e^ae^{bi}$$
This is a complex number of radius $e^a$ and of argument $b$.

Now, starting with $w\neq 0$, we define $a=\ln |w|$ and $b=\arg w$. $z=\ln|w|+i\arg w$ gives us $w=e^z$.

Answer (score 0):

Approaching thorugh real anologues;

First part: If $x+iy$ $|e^z|=e^{x}\neq o$ implies $e^z\neq 0.$

Second part:For $w\neq 0,$ the polar form is given by $w=|w|e^{i\theta}$ and every positive real can be expressed as an exponential function, so in this case $|w|=e^{\log |w|},$ by whcih we will have 
$w=e^{\log |w|}.e^{i\theta}= e^{\log |w|+i\theta}=e^{z},$ where $z=\log |w|+i\theta.$